# Is the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups, infinite-groups, general-linear-group

> Let $a=\begin{pmatrix} \xi & 0\\ 0 & \overline{\xi} \end{pmatrix}$ and $b=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ elements of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ where $\xi=e^{2\pi i /n}\in \mathbb{C}$.
>
> Prove that $D_{2n}=\left\{1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1},b,ab,a^2b,...,a^{n-1}b\right\}$ is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$.

It's clear that $1\in D_{2n}$ is the neutral element and the operation is closed in $D_{2n}$.

About the inverses elements, I have computed that $1^{-1}=I_2=1, (a^i)^{-1}=a^{n-i}, b^{-1}=b$ that are in $D_{2n}$ where $i=1,...,n-1$. But I have problems trying to find the inverse of the elements of the form $a^i b$ where $i=1,...,n-1$.

I think that $(a^i b)^{-1}=ba^{n-i}$. However $ba^{n-i}\notin D_{2n}$. Hence $D_{2n}$ is not a subgroup?

Comment: Is $b a^{n-i}$ equal (as a matrix) to $a^j b$ for some value of $j$?

Comment: You say $ba^{n-i}\notin D_{2n}$. Can you prove that?

Comment: I have seen that $b a^{n-i}$ has the form $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \overline{\xi}^{n-i} \\ \xi^{n-i} & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $a^j b$ has the form $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \xi ^j \\ \overline{\xi}^j & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. That is, with $j=n-i$ we have the same matrix with the complex number conjugate. But I don't finish to see how to relate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a subgroup.

I will use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20one,is%20also%20in%20the%20subset.).

Since, indeed, $1\in D_{2n}$, we have $D_{2n}\neq\varnothing$.

Since $a,b\in GL_2(\Bbb C)$, we have $D_{2n}\subseteq GL_2(\Bbb C)$.

Observe that

$$ba^{-1}=ab, b^2=1, a^n=1.\tag{1}$$

Consider arbitrary $a^jb^e, a^kb^f\in D_{2n}$.

Then we have

$$\begin{align}
a^jb^e(a^kb^f)^{-1}&=a^jb^e(b^{-f}a^{-k})\quad\text{(as }D_{2n}\subseteq GL_2(\Bbb C)\text{)}\\
&=a^j(b^{e-f}a^{-k})\\
&=a^j(a^kb^{e-f})\\
&=a^{j+k}b^{e-f},
\end{align}$$

where we can take $j+k$ modulo $n$ and $e-f$ modulo $2$ by $(1)$. But then $a^jb^e(a^kb^f)^{-1}=a^{j+k}b^{e-f}\in D_{2n}$.

Hence $D_{2n}\le GL_2(\Bbb C)$.